# Implement search on field value in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search, search-query

How to query the SharePoint 2013 Search Service Application so that I will get results on the basis of field value in list?

Eg. If the value is `Active`, it should be shown in search, if not active the record or page should not be searchable.

Answer (score 0):

That is not really how the indexer works. It indexes everything it has access to. One inexpensive approach would be to add a rule to the Result Sources that includes a Managed Property for your Active field like `Active=1`.

The problem is that if anyone "knows" search they can easily circumvent this approach. If you want to prevent the content from being indexed you will have to write a protocol handler so that the items are never indexed. THis is a much larger undertaking.